# Update if exist, else insert

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have a table containing following columns:

1. pk
2. empID
3. peer_empID

The data is something like this:

```
pk    empID    peer_empID
1      5          27
2      5          94
3      5          67
```

Data is displayed to the user like this:

[image]

User can Add **Peers**, Modify selected Peer and Delete them as well. Finally by clicking on save:

1. Deleted Peers will be deleted
2. Changed Peers will be updated
3. Added Peers will added

and it will be stored in the database.

I have to write a query to update if changed, insert if doesn't exist and delete if removed from the front end.

**I tried this:**

```
IF not exists (select empID, peer_empID from assignPeers where empID = @empID and peer_empID = @peer_empID)

    BEGIN
        insert into assignPeers (empID, peer_empID) values (@empID, @peer_empID)
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
        update assignPeers set peer_empID = -->here is the problem.. how will I define the condition to update? <-- 
        where empID = @empID and peer_empID = @peer_empID
    END
```

Kindly suggest me what to do in this scenario?

Comment: This is a very common scenario.  Google `UPSERT` for info.  Most RDBMS have syntax for this now.

Comment: Have you looked into the `MERGE` statement? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @SchmitzIT I didn't know about it. I check it out.

Comment: Its fine ! I got it. But how will know which rows are to be deleted? or user has changed the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, I think you do not have many choices... You must store the original primary key, and the new one, and try updating with both SET and WHERE statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assignPeers WHERE empID = @empID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE assignPeers set peer_empID =  @peer_empID
    WHERE empID = @empID 
END
ELSE    
    INSERT into assignPeers (empID, peer_empID) values (@empID, @peer_empID) 
END
```

Would you please try with above code?

Comment: Yeah I did it with the same logic